# Been unable to find where the HTML text in this gatsby template is and how to change it. Very confusing website structure

Tags: javascript, gatsby, prismic.io

I have been trying to find where the HTML text in a particular gatsby template is.

I have been trying to find this text [image]

But I have been unable to find where this text is written in the folder. I was wondering if anyone can explain where I may find it and how this particular template works?

The template's link: https://github.com/margueriteroth/gatsby-prismic-starter-prist

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably that is not stored in the source code, but maybe the in the prismic CMS?